I handed in my physical copies of my PhD thesis too late (Germany) - what are my options?
I am an international student who started my PhD program in 2014 in Germany. I defended my thesis in fall 2021, after having moved to a different country while writing my thesis. After the defense, I did not receive the corrections to my thesis for several months due to incorrect address. Compounded with that were Covid-related delays. I'm writing briefly, but due to severe mental health issues (traumatic stress, anxiety), I was very late in submitting the final copies of the thesis to library (2024).
The crux of the problem is that the regulations state that the final copies of the thesis must be delivered within 1 year of the date of the defense (i.e. fall 2022). And any extensions to this date must be requested prior to the deadline.
The PhD thesis was well received, with publications, and the defense was passed well. Now after more than half a decade of blood, sweat, and tears, I will fail a PhD due to an administrative rule. Is there a remedy for this situation? Are there lawyers that would be able to convince the dean?

Have you asked for an extension? Would they consider Covid as a factor (don't know until you ask)? Would they redo the defense? All questions for a specific institution/dean.

What have you actually tried so far? Anything?

If you want legal advise, then you need to talk to a lawyer not to random people on the Internet. My first step however would be to talk to your advisor explain the situation, and see if she/he/they know who to talk to. Maybe they can talk on your behalf. Often things can be resolved without all the legal trouble and all the costs that come with that.

Remember that no lawyer can convince a dean. As soon as a lawyer gets involved, the entire case moves on to the legal staff of the university, which is probably not what you want. At least not as a first step.

Nobody here can answer your question. Only your university can answer your question.

Thank you for all the helpful suggestions. For transparency, I wrote this question in first-person but I'm not the one with the problem.
The advisors have been contacted and now the research dean is the next person to talk to. I just wanted to exhaust all avenues and crowdsource some opinions/experiences. Thanks.

Any reasonable academic institution is likely to grant post-facto extensions for a bunch on unfortunate bagatelle delays - not bagatelle for you, to be sure, but all reasons given are minor in the grand scheme of things as far as the department is concerned. It is not that you have actively conspired to drag everyone by the nose, made committees convene multiple times and waste their time, etc. - instead, you were simply caught in a cascade of unfortunate events.
Unless you made enemies, I do not think people will want to sabotage the work of a semi-decade, and typically academia is good at finding ways around formalia that hamper academically worthy achievements, especially in Germany.
That being said, as some comments mention, don't involve a lawyer if at all possible. This should be considered to be only the absolutely last resort. You need to consider this the nuclear option from which there is no return. No academic will touch a sue-happy candidate with a barge-pole.

I'm not familiar with the term bagatella.

bagatelle - approximately translatable as "trifle". With less of the negative connotation.

Thanks! Does that mean the original answer has a typo? (bagatella vs bagatelle)

I intended to use it as a foreign word, that's why 'a' felt more appropriate.

Apparently "bagatelle" is French but the Norwegian "bagatella" means the same thing :) In any case, I think it would probably be clearer answer to just use an English word.

Bagatelle is an English word.

My point was that the origin is French. But as you said, bagatella is not an English word. I also think it's not a particularly well known English word.

@MichaelMior After your comment, I checked. Bagatella is not English, but bagatelle is. Do you insist on me changing it? I feel that "trifle" is too dismissive.

It's your answer, so I can't really insist on anything, but I do think a decent percentage of readers would not know what the word means. "Small" or "minor" could also potentially work.

@MichaelMior Got it. I have reflected and decided to keep the word. I find it gets the nuance just right and checking the spectrum of its meanings is, nowadays, just a few keystrokes away for the reader. Personally, 1. I enjoy learning new words and connotations, 2. I am not a fan of oversimplification of language; I believe in exerting effort to keep it rich. Thanks for the suggestion, in any case.

Extensions to the deadline for submitting a PhD thesis are extremely common.  Only your university can decide if you will get an extension.  Just ask the administrators for instructions.
